# MySQL users changed their IP address. What's the best way to deal with this?

Tags: mysql

I have a number of users who are connecting to MySQL over a VPN, so we have grants along the lines of `grant select on foo.* to user@ipaddress1` and so on.

This week, the IP used on the VPN changed to **address2**, so `user@ipaddress1` grants no longer work.

What's the best way to handle updating the user and grant information in MySQL to reflect this change?

Note that the grants are a serious mess, because some users are excluded from particular columns in particular tables, so we've had to do grants around the excluded objects.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Apparently, the right way to do this is:

```
RENAME USER user@ipaddress1 TO user@ipaddress2;
```

For more details see the [RENAME USER Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-user.html) section

This takes care of all the grants.

Comment: Works fine for MySQL version **8**

Answer (score 5):

Just update the host field in your MySQL user table:

```
update mysql.user set Host = 'newIP' where Host = 'oldIP';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Tried that: it doesn't work if there are grants.

Comment: OH...good call. My bad.

Comment: This should work just fine, you just need to execute the `flush privileges` statement after you manually manipulate any of the privileges tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dedicated subnet for your VPN users the following syntax works well.

```
GRANT ALL ... user_name@'192.168.1.%'
```

Comment: That doesn't help with the existing users at a specific IP.  We would still have to redo all the grants, even if we're using a range the next time through.

Comment: You can update the existing users with the same syntax.